# Vim displays coloring marks on backspace

Tags: vim

Every time I'm in insert mode, when I press backspace, something like on image below happens. On save everything is saved properly, but until then - it looks broken.

It seems like shell colour characters, but I'm not really sure.

After some testing, and removing pieces of .vimrc, seems like it's issue of [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate).

What could be the reason?

[image: weird display]

Comment: Does this happen if you try using different terminal emulators? I vaguely remember having a similar issue about a year ago, and it was due to my tmux/terminal settings not playing nicely with encoding.

Comment: It happens through kitty, xfce4-terminal, and guake - so all terminals i have tested.

Comment: Are you running airline? Is it possible you could post/link your .vimrc?

Comment: I am using airline, and sure, i can link to my .vimrc. Actually, I should have done that on day 1 :P https://github.com/Bugari/my_vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: Can you try `set t_ut=` in your .vimrc?

Comment: Does this happen in gvim, also? Try `set t_Co=256` out of gvim, as well.

Comment: I cannot test t_ut right now, but it does *not* happen on gvim, only on vim

Answer (score 1):

`s:ExtraMappings()` defines a map for <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in [`plugin/delimitMate.vim`](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/plugin/delimitMate.vim):

```
" If pair is empty, delete both delimiters:
inoremap <silent> <Plug>delimitMateBS <C-R>=delimitMate#BS()<CR>
if !hasmapto('<Plug>delimitMateBS','i')
  if empty(maparg('<BS>', 'i'))
    silent! imap <unique> <buffer> <BS> <Plug>delimitMateBS
  endif
  if empty(maparg('<C-H>', 'i'))
    silent! imap <unique> <buffer> <C-h> <Plug>delimitMateBS
  endif
endif
```

Note that `<Plug>delimitMateBS` is mapped to `<C-R>=delimitMate#BS()<CR>`. `<C-R>=` enters an expression, and that expression will be returned by `delimitMate#BS()`. See `:help c_CTRL-R_=`:

```
'='     the expression register: you are prompted to
        enter an expression (see expression)
```

`delimitMate#BS()` returns key inputs to handle pairs in [`autoload/delimitMate.vim`](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/autoload/delimitMate.vim):

```
function! delimitMate#BS() " {{{
  if s:is_forbidden("")
    let extra = ''
  elseif &bs !~ 'start\|2'
    let extra = ''
  elseif delimitMate#WithinEmptyPair()
    let extra = "\<Del>"
  elseif s:is_space_expansion()
    let extra = "\<Del>"
  elseif s:is_cr_expansion()
    let extra = repeat("\<Del>",
          \ len(matchstr(getline(line('.') + 1), '^\s*\S')))
  else
    let extra = ''
  endif
  return "\<BS>" . extra
endfunction " }}} delimitMate#BS()
```

By looking into the code, you can know the return value can be:

- `"\<BS>"`
- `"\<BS>\<Del>"`
- `"\<BS>\<Del>\<Del>"`
- …

So as I think, it's an issue of handling <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. See `:help :fixdel` for additional information.

```
:fix[del]               Set the value of 't_kD':
                                't_kb' is     't_kD' becomes
                                  CTRL-?        CTRL-H
                                not CTRL-?      CTRL-?

                        (CTRL-? is 0177 octal, 0x7f hex) {not in Vi}

                        If your delete key terminal code is wrong, but the
                        code for backspace is alright, you can put this in
                        your .vimrc:
                                :fixdel
                        This works no matter what the actual code for
                        backspace is.

                        If the backspace key terminal code is wrong you can
                        use this:
                                :if &term == "termname"
                                :  set t_kb=^V<BS>
                                :  fixdel
                                :endif
                        Where "^V" is CTRL-V and "<BS>" is the backspace key
                        (don't type four characters!).  Replace "termname"
                        with your terminal name.

                        If your <Delete> key sends a strange key sequence (not
                        CTRL-? or CTRL-H) you cannot use ":fixdel".  Then use:
                                :if &term == "termname"
                                :  set t_kD=^V<Delete>
                                :endif
                        Where "^V" is CTRL-V and "<Delete>" is the delete key
                        (don't type eight characters!).  Replace "termname"
                        with your terminal name.
```

Comment: Sadly, it did not help - moreover, it works even worse after adding it ;P not really sure how to fix it with :fixdel. Also, I noticed, when I'm in insert mode, there are similar weird characters at end of --INSERT-- notification.